# Create 1 ReturnObject from 2 JSON object arrays with Typescript

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I'm trying to create a JSON with an Excel office script, to use this JSON in a Microsoft Power Automate flow to create Item master data . My problem is that I don't get the message header and the Item details into 1 ReturnObject. I'm a beginner in JS and Typescript.

I made a script for the messageHeader export interfase and this works fine. See Stack overflow example 1.
I made a script for the itemDetails export interfase and this also works fine. See Stack overflow example 2.
But cant find a way to merge those 2 into one script in which the export interface contains the messagHeader and the itemDetail data. See stack overflow example 3.

**
Stack overflow example 1: messageHeader.**

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // get Worksheet
    const sheetHeaderData = workbook.getWorksheet("MessageIdentification")
 
   // Get Range and texts
    const headerDataRange = sheetHeaderData.getRange("A1:F2")
    const headerData = headerDataRange.getTexts()
        
  // Create an array of JSON objects for the messageHeader.
    let returnHeaderObjects: messageIdentification[] = [];
    if (headerDataRange.getRowCount() > 0) {
    returnHeaderObjects = returnHeaderObjectValues(headerData);
  }

  // Log the information and return it for a Power Automate flow.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(returnHeaderObjects));
  return returnHeaderObjects

}

// This function converts a 2D array of values into a generic JSON object.
function returnHeaderObjectValues(values: string[][]): messageIdentification[] {
  let objectArray: messageIdentification[] = [];
  let objectKeys: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      objectKeys = values[i]
      continue;
    }

    let object: {
      [key: string]: string
    } = {}
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      object[objectKeys[j]] = values[i][j]
    }

    objectArray.push(object as unknown as messageIdentification);
  }

  return objectArray;
}

export interface Root {
  MessageIdentification: messageIdentification
  Items: item[]
}

export interface messageIdentification {
  Tenant: string
  DateTimeCreated: string
  Sender: string
  Receiver: string
  MessageType: string
  Version: number
}

export interface item {
  ItemId: string
  Description: string
  Client: string
  ItemUnitOfMeasurements: ItemUnitOfMeasurement[]
}

export interface ItemUnitOfMeasurement {
  FactorToBase: number
  ItemUnitOfMeasure: string
  BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement: boolean
}
```

**
Stack overflow example 2: itemDetails.**

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): item[] {
    // Get worksheet.
  const itemDetails = workbook.getWorksheet('Items').getTables()[0];

    // Get Range and texts
  const itemdetailstexts = itemDetails.getRange().getTexts();

    // Create an array of JSON objects for the itemDetails.
      let returnDetailObjects: item[] = [];
      if (itemDetails.getRowCount() > 0) {
        returnDetailObjects = returnDetailObjectValues(itemdetailstexts);
    }

    // Log the information and return it for a Power Automate flow.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(returnDetailObjects));
    return returnDetailObjects
}

// This function converts a 2D array of values into a generic JSON object.
function returnDetailObjectValues(values: string[][]): item[] {
  let objectArray: item[] = [];
    let objectKeys: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            objectKeys = values[i]
            continue;
        }

        let object: { [key: string]: string } = {}
        for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            object[objectKeys[j]] = values[i][j]
        }

      objectArray.push(object as unknown as item);
    }

    return objectArray;
}

export interface Root {
  MessageIdentification: messageIdentification
  Items: item[]
}
export interface messageIdentification {
  Tenant: string
  DateTimeCreated: string
  Sender: string
  Receiver: string
  MessageType: string
  Version: number
}

export interface item {
  ItemId: string
  Description: string
  Client: string
  ItemUnitOfMeasurements: ItemUnitOfMeasurement[]
}

export interface ItemUnitOfMeasurement {
  FactorToBase: number
  ItemUnitOfMeasure: string
  BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement: boolean
}
```

**
Stack overflow example 3: unsuccesfull attempt to merge messageHeader and itemDetails.**

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // get Workbooksheet
    const sheetMessageHeader = workbook.getWorksheet("MessageIdentification")
    const sheetItemDetails = workbook.getWorksheet('Items').getTables()[0];

    // Get Range and texts
    const headerDataRange = sheetMessageHeader.getRange("A1:F2")
    const messageHeaderTexts = headerDataRange.getTexts()
    const itemDetailsTexts = sheetItemDetails.getRange().getTexts();
    
    // Create an array of JSON objects for the messageHeader.
    let returnHeaderObjects: messageIdentification[] = [];
    if (headerDataRange.getRowCount() > 0) {
      returnHeaderObjects = returnHeaderObjectValues(messageHeaderTexts);

    // Create an array of JSON objects for the itemDetails.
    let returnDetailObjects: items[] = [];
    if (sheetItemDetails.getRowCount() > 0) {
      returnDetailObjects = returnDetailObjectValues(itemDetailsTexts);
    }
  }

  // Log the information and return it for a Power Automate flow.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(returnHeaderObjects));
  return returnHeaderObjects

  // Log the information and return it for a Power Automate flow.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(returnDetailObjects));
  return returnDetailObjects

}

// This function converts a 2D array of the messageHeader texts into a generic JSON object.
function returnHeaderObjectValues(values: string[][]): messageIdentification [] {
  let objectArray: messageIdentification[] = [];
  let objectKeys: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      objectKeys = values[i]
      continue;
    }

    let object: {
      [key: string]: string
    } = {}
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      object[objectKeys[j]] = values[i][j]
    }

    objectArray.push(object as unknown as messageIdentification);
  }

  return objectArray;
}

// This function converts a 2D array of itemDetail texts into a generic JSON object.
function returnDetailObjectValues(values: string[][]): items[] {
  let objectArray: items[] = [];
  let objectKeys: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      objectKeys = values[i]
      continue;
    }

    let object: { [key: string]: string } = {}
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      object[objectKeys[j]] = values[i][j]
    }

    objectArray.push(object as unknown as items);
  }

  return objectArray;
}



export interface Root {
  MessageIdentification: messageIdentification
  Items: items[]
}

export interface messageIdentification {
  Tenant: string
  DateTimeCreated: string
  Sender: string
  Receiver: string
  MessageType: string
  Version: string
}

export interface items {
  ItemId: string
  Description: string
  Client: string
  ItemUnitOfMeasurements: ItemUnitOfMeasurement[]
}

export interface ItemUnitOfMeasurement {
  FactorToBase: number
  ItemUnitOfMeasure: string
  BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement: boolean
}
```

**The Excel data I used for the Header**

[image]

**The Excel data I used for the Items**

[image]

**The JSON result I expect is:**

```
{
    "MessageIdentification": {
        "Tenant": "demo",
        "DateTimeCreated": "2022-03-29T12:21:31.174Z",
        "Sender": "x",
        "Receiver": "y",
        "MessageType": "Item",
        "Version": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "ItemId": "90001",
            "Description": "Excel2JSON test 1",
            "Client": "BV Test",
            "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                {
                    "FactorToBase": 1,
                    "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "Box",
                    "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": true
                    }             
            ]
        },
        {
            "ItemId": "90002",
            "Description": "Excel2JSON test 2",
            "Client": "BV Test",
            "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                {
                    "FactorToBase": 1,
                    "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "Box",
                    "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": true
                    }             
            ]
        },
        {
            "ItemId": "90003",
            "Description": "Excel2JSON test 3",
            "Client": "BV Test",
            "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                {
                    "FactorToBase": 1,
                    "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "Box",
                    "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": true
                    }             
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not far from working.

- `getObject` is recursive function to get the JSON
- `enum jsonMode` is used to define extract mode

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// ----------------------
  const sheetHeaderData = workbook.getWorksheet("MessageIdentification")
  const headerDataRange = sheetHeaderData.getTables()[0];
  const headerData = headerDataRange.getRange().getTexts();
  let headerObjects: messageIdentification[] = [];
  if (headerDataRange.getRowCount() > 0) {
    headerObjects = getObject(headerData, jsonMode.Header);
  }
// ----------------------
  const itemDetail = workbook.getWorksheet("Items").getTables()[0];
  const itemDetailTexts = itemDetail.getRange().getTexts();
  let itemDetailObjects: item[] = [];
  if (itemDetail.getRowCount() > 0) {
    itemDetailObjects = getObject(itemDetailTexts, jsonMode.Item);
  }
// ----------------------
  let objRootArray: Root[] = [];
  let objkeyValue: { [key: string]: (string | object) } = {};
  const detailKey: string = "MessageIdentification";
  const headerKey: string = "Items";
  objkeyValue[detailKey] = itemDetailObjects;
  objkeyValue[headerKey] = headerObjects;
  objRootArray.push(objkeyValue as unknown as Root);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(objRootArray));
}
// ----------------------
function getObject(values: string[][], mode: jsonMode): object {
  let resultArray: [] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    let objKeyValue: { [key: string]: (string | object) } = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
      if (mode === jsonMode.Header && j === 3) {
        let meaArray: string[][] = [];
        meaArray[0] = [];
        meaArray[1] = [];
        for (let k = j; k < values[0].length; k++) {
          meaArray[0][k - 3] = values[0][k];
          meaArray[1][k - 3] = values[i][k];
        }
        let measureObjects: unknown[] = [];
        measureObjects = getObject(meaArray, jsonMode.Measure);
        objKeyValue["ItemUnitOfMeasurements"] = measureObjects;
        break;
      } else {
        objKeyValue[values[0][j]] = values[i][j];
      }
    }
    resultArray.push(objKeyValue);
  }
  return resultArray;
}
// ----------------------
enum jsonMode {
  Header = "Header",
  Item = "Item",
  Measure = "Measure",
}
// ----------------------
export interface Root {
  MessageIdentification: messageIdentification
  Items: item[]
}
export interface messageIdentification {
  Tenant: string
  DateTimeCreated: string
  Sender: string
  Receiver: string
  MessageType: string
  Version: string
}
export interface item {
  ItemId: string
  Description: string
  Client: string
  ItemUnitOfMeasurements: ItemUnitOfMeasurement[]
}
export interface ItemUnitOfMeasurement {
  FactorToBase: string
  ItemUnitOfMeasure: string
  BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement: string
}
```

**Output**

```json
[
    {
        "MessageIdentification": [
            {
                "Tenant": "demo",
                "DataTimeCreated": "10/24/2023",
                "Sender": "X",
                "Receiver": "Y",
                "MessageType": "Item",
                "Version": "3"
            }
        ],
        "Items": [
            {
                "ItemId": "90001",
                "Description": "Excel2JSON test1",
                "Client": "BV Test",
                "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                    {
                        "FactorToBase": "1",
                        "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "BOX",
                        "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": "TRUE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ItemId": "90002",
                "Description": "Excel2JSON test2",
                "Client": "BV Test",
                "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                    {
                        "FactorToBase": "2",
                        "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "BOX",
                        "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": "TRUE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ItemId": "90003",
                "Description": "Excel2JSON test3",
                "Client": "BV Test",
                "ItemUnitOfMeasurements": [
                    {
                        "FactorToBase": "3",
                        "ItemUnitOfMeasure": "BOX",
                        "BaseItemUnitOfMeasurement": "TRUE"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]